# Automatically ask for certain information on Apache vhost questions

Tags: feature-request

Pretty much every time someone asks a question regarding Apache virtual hosts, the very first thing someone asks is "Can you post the output of `apache2ctl -S`/`httpd -S`?"

It would be awesome if SF detected these kinds of questions and prompted the asker to enter the appropriate information, possibly in a field dedicated to this particular information (thanks @AdrianK!)

This field wouldn't *necessarily* be mandatory. ☺

[image: Clippy]

Comment: Related: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1631/ways-to-improve-the-quality-of-questions-concerning-some-tags-tag-triggered-sug

Comment: I find the very idea of "Clippy", or anyone actually having it enabled, downright offensive.

Comment: I once had a dream where Clippy was slowly sinking/melting into a giant vat of molten metal - his little 'hand' was the last thing to enter the glowing pool...

Answer (score 2):

I think the Tag Wiki block that Iain pointed out ( [Ways to improve the quality of questions concerning some tags (tag-triggered suggestions?)](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1631/ways-to-improve-the-quality-of-questions-concerning-some-tags-tag-triggered-sug) ) is about the closest we're going to get on this --  Might be worth raising on the new Stack Exchange meta once it's live though.

I'm basically just throwing an answer on this question so we can knock out one more unanswered question on Meta (no devs have looked at this in 3 months, I doubt they're interested :-( )