# What should the community take away from panel-gate?

Tags: discussion

The event that has been dubbed [panel-gate](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8054/abrupt-change-in-moderation-staff) by members of the community has sparked emotion and even outrage from the community with regard to the actions of some, and how the events unfolded.

### The facts

- The head community manager noticed a moderator account closing questions with a "canned" comment
- The community manager thought the closings were too close together and as a result, suspicious.
- Upon further investigation the community manager noticed some questions that didn't exactly fit the canned close reason, and became even more suspicious.
- The community manager searched meta but found no recent mention of a closing campaign, and only a single mention of what was happening in an almost defunct chat room.
- To protect the integrity of the site, the community manager suspended the moderator's mod status, pending an investigation into the event and communication with the moderator.

---

- The moderator was closing questions that are explicitly off topic.
- The moderator believed he was acting on the consensus of the community.
- There are questions on meta that confirm the moderator's beliefs.
- A portion of the community has also confirmed these beliefs.
- The moderator has since resigned from his duties in response to this incident.

---

Now that the situation has slightly died down, I wanted to create a question where the community can talk about what we should *take away* from this event. This question isn't about finger pointing or name calling, hopefully all of that is over. It *is* about what's left of the community can do better to ensure something like this doesn't happen again. We lost a very active moderator and other active high rep members over what appears to be nothing more than a communication disconnect.

To clarify, by *community* I mean both the SF community and the community managers. Anyone who has something constructive to say has the floor.

Comment: I think this should wait for Shog to post his version of the events...  Although I guess he could just edit them into this question.  In any case, I don't think the final take-away can be decided until we know _why_ he thought his reactions (including "you're lying," etc.) were appropriate.

Comment: I agree @Ward, these points came straight from his post though, I tried to leave out any drama or emotion that wasn't relevant.

Comment: I agree; since this isn't over yet, I wonder if perhaps this is premature.

Comment: @Michael It probably is, but the real issue at hand as I see it is the one we had before panelgate and will continue to have afterwards.

Comment: I hope you both will agree though there are some things that can immediately be taken away though in regards to what has happened thus far.

Comment: I'm afraid that without a full, factual, statement from the SE staff it'll be hard to feel like I'm reading the other responses bias free. The communication from one side has been a lot more prevalent than from the other. Which doesn't mean people should refrain from giving their opinions, I know I don't, but it sure feels like it's tainting everything I'm reading.

Comment: @Reaces I remained impartial when presenting the facts of both sides. Everything presented from the Community Managers point of view was taken from his own meta post, and his own comments.

Comment: @BigHomie Don't misunderstand, I have _nothing_ to say against your post. It looks fair and it even seems like you're going out of your way to make sure that you don't misrepresent the Community Managers. I'm simply saying it's hard not to notice that the Serverfault's core users side has been more vocal. And unfortunately it's kind of starting to look like we're talking amongst ourselves a bit much.

Comment: @Reaces no we're good, I read you loud and clear, I'm actually hoping Shog and some others will chime in here as well, we just have to give (at least Shog) some time. What I didn't want though is to bring this up ages from now after its been forgotten.

Comment: My biggest takeaway is that you can't just go and whack the suffix "-gate" on the end of a noun. THATS NOT HOW IT WORKS PEOPLE.

Comment: @MarkHenderson your annoyance at the gate issue will now be known as Gate-gate...

Comment: As much as you're trying to so the postmortem correctly -- HUZZAH -- it really needs to wait until after the incident report has been written and distributed. Otherwise we end up making assumptions that can disrupt the fact-only analysis of the issue.

Comment: @ScottPack that's a fair assessment, in addition though: There's no harm in posting this question early, everyone can wait for SE to weigh in before giving their thoughts if they like. I guess it could get pushed down meta's front page :(

Comment: @BigHomie It probably won't hurt but it certainly can. The purpose of a postmortem is to review the facts of SB incident with as little attribution or qualitative analysis as possible. The goal is to identify not only which button was clicked incorrectly but more importantly what was the root cause that resulted in the button being couched incorrectly. By discussing it before the report had verb released we run the risk of tainting the process with incomplete, or incorrect,  data.

Answer (score 20):

What should the *community* take away?

### Stop looking for a savior

I've watched one moderator after another tire and burn out here, but somehow the reason behind it never came into focus for me until this weekend: there is very, very little community moderation here.

The support I've seen for Hopeless and the overt hatred and bitterness I've seen poured out on other members of the mod team are two sides of the same coin: folks dissatisfied with the site and wanting *someone else* to fix it for them. As long as you can say you're doing that, you're golden. But if you falter, if you find yourself looking for help tackling a project too big for a few people to do alone, then it's, "What good are you, you used-up has-been;" time for a new *great white hope* to chew up and spit out.

This isn't accomplishing anything. Moderators can accomplish a lot - and you've all been lucky to have a long string of them willing to pick up the slack for you with very little complaint - but expecting a moderator team to handle the majority of the moderation on a site like this is naive; a good moderator excels at doing the things you cannot, but your role in the moderation process doesn't end when you cast your vote... Abdicating responsibility once the election is over does a disservice to yourself, to the moderators you elect, and to the community as a whole.

You get the site that **you** work to build. If you're not willing to pitch in, then expecting anyone else to do it for you is irresponsible.

I'm being blunt, but I don't think there's a nice way to say this. Whether you like it or not, Stack Exchange is and always has been a *community*-moderated system; if you don't want to be a part of that, then don't expect anything to change on your account.

That's what y'all should take away. But you asked what I (or others at SE) should take away...

### Better, earlier warnings

There are [eleven of us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do) doing this sort of support, across 140+ sites. We try hard to be aware and responsive to issues everywhere, but don't have the luxury of spending all of our time anywhere. Sometimes, stuff gets missed...

**But none of this should have been missed.**

I should've sat down with Hopeless *his first week after being elected*, gone over the actions he took, and suggested better / easier / **more open** ways of doing them. But I didn't see most of what he was doing; no one did.

My takeaway here is that we need better monitoring tools, better guidance for moderator tools, and warning systems when activity goes too far outside the norm. The ones we have were probably *barely* adequate in 2009, but they're next-to-useless now. I'll be writing up proposals for this over the next few weeks; a good bit of this information can and should be public, at least for trusted users, so I'll post those proposals on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

On a personal note, I want to apologize to all of you. It's my job to keep an eye on things like this, to provide guidance and correction to those involved *before* they get wildly out of hand. I didn't, they did, and I'm sorry.

Comment: +1, great feedback, and indeed, `..If you're not willing to pitch in, then expecting anyone else to do it for you is irresponsible.`

Comment: In addition, there is a statement in an answer that says `There is a perception that requests directed at SE staff typically get ignored for long periods of time.` Are you saying this is due to the massive amount of sites that your team oversees? Is there anything you see that could improve that?

Comment: Thank you for this and your other posts, Shog9. I truly do appreciate the work that went into them as well as your candor in describing what you could have done better. I think one thing that was missed (which IMHO contributed in a significant way to some of the vitriol following the removal of Hopeless's diamond) is the tone you used in many of your posts and comments. It was clear you were assuming the worst of n00b, instead of assuming that he had good intentions (as you now have realized). If you'd used a more empathetic tone, I think this would have gone down in a very different way.

Comment: ...just something to consider as you handle other similar situations around SE in the future. Hopefully you won't need to do so, actually, but if you do, I find that conversations and confrontations with people go much better if they're initiated from an understanding that all involved parties are working with good intentions.

Comment: I wish I'd used a more empathetic tone as well, @EEAA - but I don't think it would've gone down any differently. I've been here once or twice before. Regardless, nothing I wrote last week had any time for proof-reading much less editing for tone; I suspect this is one of those situations where the only way I could be prepared to handle it well is to have previously handled it poorly. Hope for next time, I guess.

Comment: I think part of the problem is morale--we *do* have a [meta-tag:doomed] tag in meta, after all.  At the risk of generalizing, I believe we have a tendency as a career path to self-select for lone efforts and short, high-intensity bursts of activity, which... might not help?  I know I find the close queue depressing in large doses, myself.  I'm always relieved when the queue says, "You cannot have more close queue.  You have a close queue problem.  Go home, sober up, and do more in the morning."  ;)

Comment: Ah, see - [no one believes me when I say that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285438/we-need-more-close-votes/285486#comment154744_285486), @Katherine... But it's sooo so true. When I was young, I used to go out & pick up trash along the highway; you do that by yourself, you'll be out there all day with nothing to show for it, but you get five people lined up & you'll have *miles* behind you before you know it. When everyone does a little, together it all adds up.

Comment: Perception isn't necessarily reality, @BigHomie. [Everyone hates it when their requests go unanswered](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289274/triage-all-feature-requests-give-an-official-position-and-timeline), but even as we grow the dev team it's impossible to address more than a fraction of the requests on *any* site. *I* still have years'-old requests that haven't been addressed yet. Some requests are easier than others; [take advantage of the ones that are possible now](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6617/should-we-enable-tag-specific-popups).

Comment: @Shog9 So, does HopelessN00b get his moderator diamond back again?!?

Comment: First off, thank you for the well written and well thought out response. I have however a comment (I'm so sorry I can't ever seem to help myself!). It seems like there is a clear disconnect between the stance of moderators being picked from the members of the community that are most active in community moderation, and the lack of community votes for moderators (IE their votes are binding). I know it's been discussed to death, but what I'm mostly taking away from your post is "everyone should vote, not rely on moderators" but with each election more voting people are removed.

Comment: Maybe now you can understand [what Shane was talking about](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6701/server-fault-needs-professional-quality-questions-not-just-questions-from-profe) WRT needing new contributors, @Reaces.

Comment: @Shog9 I actually didn't connect that post with yours. As taken from the post: `with an accompanying jump in participation through community moderation (mainly close votes and down votes)`. In fact it indicates that there is enough moderation, just with a wrong approach: `spending time editing the salvageable ones, giving users a push in the right direction instead of closing `. Again, I'm having a hard time making the connection between yours and his post, neither in conflicting or affirming ways.

Comment: It's not just a matter of empathy. You let yourself get dragged into [theatrics of your own](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/what-should-server-fault-do-with-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels/8066?noredirect=1#comment17465_8066), which goes a little above and beyond that. I'm not sure why it was so hard to clarify that point or at least own up to it if it was a mistake, unless you [still have me confused for someone else](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6812/proposed-change-to-server-fault-guidelines-round-2#comment15696_6832) and have put me on a mental filter.

Comment: The only connection is the one you noted in your previous comment, @Reaces: as user-moderators are removed or remove themselves, there has to be something to replace them. And yes, I'm lumping together several separate activities here, but while editing and closing and voting and deletion are quite different actions, the goal for each is in some way to improve the contents of the site; these "meta-activities" require an ever-growing number of participants to be effective, regardless of which specific actions they focus on.

Comment: Oh, and for the record:  "The support I've seen for Hopeless and the overt hatred and bitterness I've seen poured out on other members of the mod team are two sides of the same coin: folks dissatisfied with the site and wanting someone else to fix it for them."  I'm supporting Hopeless because I like him--he's one of our regulars.  I didn't vote for him because I took his initial nomination spiel as inappropriate levity, but I think he worked hard and did his best for the site, and I was pleased with him as a moderator.

Comment: For the record, @Katherine, I'd forgotten about the election spiel until folks started bringing it up last week; folks say a lot of crazy hyperbolic stuff during elections, what matters is what they do afterwards.

Comment: Fair enough, @Shog9. Besides, inappropriate levity is just something that HopelessN00b does. For as long as I've been here, he's put goofy jokes in comments on questions that end up deleted as off-topic. Which, you know. I enjoy them *and* see why they're deleted as off-topic, so there you are.

Comment: IOW:  I feel like y'all have the impression of HopelessN00b as "that jerk people complain to us about," and those of us answering questions regularly have the impression of "class clown."  If you look at the situation as N00b being "class clown" it might look a bit different.

Comment: Answer my question!!

Comment: @Shog9 As for "I don't think it would've gone down any differently", it's very possible that the outcome in many ways would have been the same except the lasting impression of you and possibly SE staff by association. It got ugly, you made some (imo) rather unprofessional statements and I think that has damaged the trust on a different level than what the all-business let's look ahead posts focus on. (Posts which I do appreciate, I just don't think it's wise to dismiss the other aspect of what went down.)

Comment: @ewwhite: I thought HopelessN00b made it [clear](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8071) that he doesn't want to come back as a mod. Unless he changed his mind, that makes this question moot.

Comment: @Sven While it probably is moot in the sense that HopelessN00b has said he's not interested, the question is also quite tightly related to the other points that have been brought up here about owning up to ones mistakes.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist: In a way, yes, in the form "would he get it back if he wanted".

Comment: I stand by what I wrote last week, @HåkanLindqvist. You can argue my tone should've been better; that's a fair criticism. But through all of this I've been as forthcoming as possible: I've reported the facts, the conclusions I've drawn and how I arrived at those conclusions. When you're telling someone else's story, it is crucial to differentiate between your interpretation of their motivations and what they've actually admitted; anything else is simply dishonest.

Comment: I don't care if Hopeless is a jerk or a clown, @Katherine; [as far as I'm concerned, we're all jackasses.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/) The important thing is that we find ways of making this work *in spite of* personality conflicts.

Comment: Being open about what you're doing is pretty critical to being a moderator, @ewwhite. I spent entirely too much time this past week piecing together information that should've already been public; if he decides he wants to be a moderator again, we still need to have a long talk about that.

Comment: @Shog9 I'll just make the point that I didn't and still don't find it clear how you reached conclusions like that the activity was malicious; an apparent early conclusion which seems central to all that happened, as well as likely set the tone, from that point on. (Not entirely sure what to make of your last sentence, considering the circumstances.)

Comment: Well, @Shog9, you've certainly made it clear what you think of us, more than once.  Don't get me wrong:  I get that we're a pain in your anatomy right now and that further, if I were you my feelings would be hurt (and I'm sorry about that), but I really think it's time to try a different approach.

Comment: I call it as I see it, @Katherine; I've no ill-will toward any of you, but I'm not coming in here blind either. I do what I can to support y'all when asked, but ultimately what happens here - good or bad - is up to you.

Comment: I never said anything about malice, @Håkan. More than enough trouble caused by apparent carelessness or boredom though. As for my last sentence... Plenty of folks here saying I'm doing this for one reason or another, with no evidence to back that up and my own statements to the contrary - I see no reason to grant any credibility to such nonsense, even if doing so might be politically expedient.

Comment: @Shog9 Lack of evidence is *the whole problem we had with the comment in question*. It began with requests for why you said it and on what basis. Consistently refusing to address the topic is naturally going to generate speculation because it sticks out like a sore thumb: the only thing that's clear is that you don't want to revisit the topic. The perception that it leaves is that regardless of motive, you don't want to, and you aren't. That you don't see a problem with this is what enables us to get so wound up about it.

Comment: @Shog9 I'll apologize for trying to bridge that silence into a *why*, but for the sake of the others, please address it. This will be my last comment on the subject; I was convinced I was done already until Håkan got a comment from you.

Comment: @Shog9 You're right, that is not a word you used and I'm sorry if you feel that I've misrepresented the early communication. I, and others, have clearly read something into your statements that you didn't intend; for me things like "rogue moderator" and "I'll be going through server logs this weekend to attempt to determine what was actually being done here", comments like these [1](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8054/abrupt-change-in-moderation-staff#comment17363_8054), [2](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8054/abrupt-change-in-moderation-staff#comment17505_8068), ...

Comment: @Shog9 ... [3](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/what-should-server-fault-do-with-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels/8066#comment17465_8066) and the, from the get-go, rather accusatory tone all added up. I still think it would make sense to address this but I won't poke further.

Comment: All of those comments *should* make sense to you now that I've posted my full analysis, @Håkan. Incidentally, "rogue" in the context where I used it is an adjective meaning "acting alone" rather than the noun "likable scoundrel" - you could perhaps also read that title as "vigilante moderator", although that has other connotations.

Answer (score 17):

I think the biggest problem we have right now is *negative expectations*. To say that there is room for improvement in the relationship between SE and SF is an understatement. It does go a bit in both directions, to be fair. I'm going to start by stealing a quote from a [recent comment](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8054/abrupt-change-in-moderation-staff#comment17598_8068) by @RobM:

> I coach newbie sysadmins and helldesk types at work by emphasising the difference between doing something *for* the users and doing something *to* the users. This feels like SE doing something to the community, not for the community.

SF's meta users have the expectation that we're ignored by the (usually) invisible SE overlords unless there's something they want from us. There is a perception that requests directed *at* SE staff typically get ignored for long periods of time. I'll let someone else provide the research to substantiate how accurate this impression is, but that doesn't change the fact that it's a *common* impression.

When SE admins *do* take action, it's usually in regards to an interest they have brought to us instead of vice versa, and the time between proposal (when it happens) and implementation is very swift by comparison. This creates quite a bit of consternation, even if there may be no connection at all between the parties who bring these proposals to us and the ones who are allegedly ignoring us. This is all the worse if it's a change that the community isn't exactly thrilled with.

Flipping this around, I think it's a fair assessment that several SE admins probably do what they can to avoid this site unless they absolutely have to touch it. Not only do we have a reputation for being ornery when compared to the other SE communities, we're extremely critical of the actions that the SE admins *do* take for the reasons covered in the prior paragraph. They expect negativity, so when they get negativity (particularly when it involves hyperbole) a great deal of it is probably dismissed out of hand. Nothing they do is going to make us happy, and things work out easier if they set their expectations low.

### Summing it up

Looking at the larger picture objectively, this works poorly for everyone. SE admins appreciate being able to keep space between themselves and us for stress related reasons, and SF users don't appreciate it when SE admins do step in because there's an impression that they only do so for their own behest. We could try to debate who the biggest contributor to this bad relationship is, or who "started it first", but that's not going to get us anywhere.

I think the focus needs to be on what both sides can unilaterally do to improve this relationship. This does mean that the SE admins are going to need to be given an opportunity to ask us for what we can do to help them (and yes, that does include not being quite as quick to go for the jugular), but it should come with the understanding that there are needs that we need addressing as well.

I challenge both sides to begin working in this direction. It won't be easy, but our only choices are to live with each other, make each other miserable, or go our separate ways. If we continue down the road that we've been going for another year or two, the third option is increasingly going to become the only workable solution.

Comment: I'm confused as to: what SE want from SF?  what SF wants from SE?  what SE thinks it offers SF?  As a sysadmin, I'm interested in participating in SF, but I don't care who or what SE is, at all.

Comment: @Blue StackExchange admins are responsible for the backend functionality and oversight of all sites in the SE network, including SF. We have not always gotten along very well. As a new contributor I recommend not worrying about our opinions and instead form your own by observing.

Comment: Comprendez.  thanks.

Comment: Hooray, I'm quotable </zoidberg>. I do agree with a lot of what's said here. the summary in particular. Regardless of who and why, there's clearly a serious breakdown in communication and it won't get better by doing _nothing_. As users, its time to either grab a shovel and start helping to dig out, or walk away (and I honestly haven't decided which I should do myself yet). Hopefully SE will reciprocate in the same spirit with those who decide they want to continue on.

Comment: @RobM Unfortunately what I'm seeing is a lot of narrative control. The "lying" remark was made before there was a full grasp on the situation and served little purpose other than to guide public opinion. The post-mortem takeaway is that this was a data and guidance problem, and that everything else is fine outside of community participation. It's probably time for everyone who doesn't see this as solely their own fault to move on.

Comment: @AndrewB *agreed* - I've made my comments and I don't think that making them again is going to help me or anyone else at this point...

Answer (score 12):

My biggest takeaway is that it will be business as usual here next week.  Crap questions will happen, a few decent questions will surface that will get maybe 2 upvotes when 5 years ago it would get 20.  The "experts" will banter back and forth within our inner circle elsewhere and the review queues will continue to be a den of despair.  To think that anything substantial will change after all of this is a little pretentious since it seems like nothing substantial ever changes on SF short of what gets pushed to it from SE on high.  Somewhere out there HopelessN00b is crushing devops, and the beat goes on.

Comment: I do agree that this is yet another morale hit to the increasingly dwindling number of people who are willing to contribute regularly. Can't really count myself among those: I follow meta and try to contribute good Q&A's related to my areas of interest, but I use RSS feeds to skip the crap entirely and thus rarely see or touch the front page. I'm part of the problem.™

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I enjoy participating, but the community isn't as vibrant and active as it once was on the voting and answering side from what I see during my timezone.

Comment: This matches my feelings pretty closely.  I try to contribute to SF when I have free time or energy, but I have noticed the overall "feel" of Serverfault has trended towards the negative in both tone and content.  I don't pretend to have the solution; just making a sad assessment from the sidelines.

Comment: Re: upvotes. The regulars around here care way too much about crappy  content and closing questions.  If people put a fraction of the effort in to upvoting good questions (and answers), this site would be considerably better.

Comment: Agreed @DougLuxem and good to see you again!  I still miss the gaming days...

Comment: Ha, I've actually considered opening a meta "love fest" post where we shout out to people who are nice and helpful, but I don't know if it's too cheesy.  :D  You'd be on the list, though!

Comment: Hah, well I tried the Christmas of love season but it didn't seem to even make a dent.

Comment: You were really nice to me when I was a newbie.  I really appreciate that.