# VirtualBox tag warning

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

One Stack Exchange feature which is significantly underutilized here at SF is [tag warnings](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6617/126632). These pop up when a user enters a tag into their question and can provide guidance on how to use the tag or ask a better question in relation to that tag.

For VirtualBox, in particular, as we still get plenty of inappropriate questions about it, I propose the following tag warning be added:

> Questions about personal and development use of VirtualBox are off-topic at Server Fault. You may be able to get help at [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Do tag warnings prevent the such a tag from being used? Or is it just a pop-up and can people ignore it and still use the tag?

Comment: It just pops up. People can still use the tag. We have other ways of blacklisting tags, if that is necessary.

Comment: I already did something similar using the normal tag description for [plesk](http://serverfault.com/tags/plesk/info) and [cpanel](http://serverfault.com/tags/cpanel/info)  when those tags got [resurrected](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/8227/37681). Those would be suitable candidates as well - Regarding your proposed text: a warning should start with the word **"warning"**

Comment: The problem is, nobody notices the tag descriptions. But the tag warnings are pretty hard to miss.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes please.  Now.  Do it now.  NOW NOW NOW.

Comment: Omg yes!  Why are we even talking about this, just do it!!  ;)